# python - Populating Array with an indexed array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, weather

I have a numpy array called "PRECIP" with shape (2,3,3) which corresponds to (time, lat, lon)

```
array([[[ 0.05368402,  0.43843025,  0.09521903],
        [ 0.22627141,  0.12920409,  0.17039465],
        [ 0.48148674,  0.59170703,  0.41321763]],

        [[ 0.63621704,  0.11119242,  0.25992372],
        [ 0.67846732,  0.3710733 ,  0.25641174],
        [ 0.1992151 ,  0.86837441,  0.80136514]]])
```

I have another numpy array called "idx" which is a list of indices, with the shape (3, 4):

```
array([[0,0,1,1], # time
       [0,2,0,2],  # x coordinate
       [0,2,0,2]]) # y coordinate
```

So far I have been able to index the "PRECIP" variable with the "idx" variable so that I get an array with the shape (4,), ie.

```
>>>accum = PRECIP[idx[0,:],idx[1,:],idx[2,:]]
array([ 0.05368402,  0.41321763,  0.63621704,  0.80136514])
```

BUT, what I need is an array of zeros "ACCUM" with the shape (3,3), populated with the sum of "PRECIP" for each pair of coordinates in "IDX".  All other gridpoints not listed in "IDX" would be 0.

Basically I want an array "accum" that looks like this

```
>>>accum    
array([[[ 0.68990106, 0. , 0.        ], # 0.68990106 = 0.05368402 + 0.63621704
        [ 0.        , 0. , 0.        ], 
        [ 0.        , 0. , 1.21458277], # 1.21458277 =  0.41321763 + 0.80136514
```

I'd appreciate any help!  Thanks :)

Comment: It may be easier to understand what you want if you supply a small sample array of your data, and the expected output of the sample, for validation purposes

Comment: That is a good idea, I used updated my question so that it looks at a small random sample.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is:

```
array = [0.5] * 249
```

It will return an array of length 249 populated with 0.5 in each index. After that you can slice it if its necesary to retrieve the amount of elements you like.

If that is not what you want, you can use dictionaries and add a key that is the tuple that you want this way.

```
dict = {(40, 249): array}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert any NaNs in the Lat and Lon columns of PRECIP to zero, then sum them and reshape the result.

```
np.nan_to_num(PRECIP[idx[1,:], idx[2,:]]).sum(axis=1).reshape(PRECIP.shape[1], PRECIP.shape[2])
```